# How to import localized version of a configuration file

Tags: configuration

With drupal, you can import a single config file.

Let say it is a view config file and let say that this view has been translated in french and has produced a locallized config file under the "fr" folder of the config folder (`wiews.view.view_name.yml`)

How can I import this single config? In other words, how can I import the translations of this view into another site (same UUID)

Comment: Export config, add this file in the fr folder, import config, done.

Comment: Many thanks. I have created a zip file containing the updated fr config and I used the import feature. After that I got "ready to import config".  Thus I used the "update" tab, select my sync folder but noting happens...